# Regex pattern to match phrases in brackets

Tags: regex

i have problem with regex that should accepts phrases like:

```
"'value'",
"NOT 'value'",
"'value' AND 'value1'",
"'value' OR 'value1'",
"'value' AND NOT 'value1'",
"'value' OR NOT 'value1'",
"'value' AND 'value1' AND 'value2'",
"'value' AND 'value1' OR 'value2'",
"'value' AND 'value1' OR NOT 'value2'",
"('foo' AND 'bar') OR ('baz' AND 'que')",
"('foo' AND 'bar')",
"('foo' OR 'bar')",
"(NOT 'foo' OR 'bar')",
"('NOT 'foo' OR NOT 'bar')",
"('foo' OR NOT 'bar')"
```

and not accept:

```
"value",
"AND value",
"OR value",
"NOT value",
"'value' 'value2'",
"'value' OR 'value2' 'value3'",
"'value' AND 'value2' 'value3'",
"'value' NOT 'value2' 'value3'",
"(foo AND 'bar') OR ('baz' AND 'que')",
"('foo' 'bar')",
"('foo OR 'bar')"
```

I have regex: `^(?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*')(?:(?: AND | OR )(?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*'))*$` but it doesnt work for brackets. Could you help me?

Comment: Regular expressions are not really good at determining "inside" and "outside". This is typically a job for a recursive-descent parser.

Comment: Are you expecting readers to reverse-engineer your examples to figure out your question? You need to state your question before presenting examples for illustration.

Comment: Add the expected output for each line that match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate this regex from following grammar: https://regex101.com/r/bXE6kx/1

```
%0 = "%j"
%s = '[^']*'
%n = (?:NOT )?%s
%o = (?:%n(?: (?:AND|OR) %n)*)
%b = (?:%o|\(%o\))
%j = %b(?: (?:AND|OR) %b)*
```

resulting in regex

```
^(?:(?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*'(?: (?:AND|OR) (?:NOT )?'[^']*')*)|\((?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*'(?: (?:AND|OR) (?:NOT )?'[^']*')*)\))(?: (?:AND|OR) (?:(?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*'(?: (?:AND|OR) (?:NOT )?'[^']*')*)|\((?:(?:NOT )?'[^']*'(?: (?:AND|OR) (?:NOT )?'[^']*')*)\)))*$
```

---

But seriously, if it gets two levels deeper, switch to a proper grammar parser, https://ohmjs.org/ or https://peggyjs.org/ or something